# The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Item

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I am trying to write a getter method that finds the sum of all elements in an array and returns a double. the problem is that I am passing an array of objects from another class and I am simply not aware of how to write a sum array with objects.

This is the method I'm trying to create

```
    private double getTotal() {
    double accumulator=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
        accumulator += items[i];
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

And here is the class I am using

```
public class Item {
    //class fields
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    
    //class constructor
    
    /**
     * class constructor for Item (takes in 3 arguments and sets them appropriately)
     * @param n :name
     * @param p :price
     * @param q :quantity
     */
    public Item(String n, double p, int q) {
        name =n;
        price =p;
        quantity =q;
    }
    
    //getters for all fields
    
    /**
     * getter method for name field of item class
     * @return name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    /**
     * getter method for price field of item class
     * @return price
     */
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    /**
     * getter method for quantity field of item class
     * @return quantity
     */
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    
    /**
     * getter method that computes sub total and returns it
     * @return subTotal
     */
    public double getSubTotal() {
        double subTotal = price*quantity;
        return subTotal;
    }
    
    //to String method
    
        /**
         * toString method for the item class
         */
        public String toString() {
            String output= "";
            output += String.format("%10.s%5.d%5.2f%5.2f\n",name,quantity, price,subTotal );

            return output;
        }
    
}
```

(yes I am aware of the error in the toString method, but that's another error for another time)

in my assignment I have to use the getSubTotal() method for this. and I can not set any of my methods anywhere in my program to be static. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: probably you mean: += items[i].getPrice();

Comment: I guess you need `accumulator += items[i].getSubTotal();`

Comment: this seems to do it. now all I need is that toString bug fixed :D

Comment: in `toString()` remove `.`s in `%10.s` and `%5.d`, like this: `output += String.format("%10s %5d %5.2f %5.2f\n",name,quantity, price,subTotal );`

Comment: subTotal is still not resolving to a variable

Comment: @BrainUnderflow that is because it isn't.It's a local variable within a method. change subTotal by getSubTotal(). It would be best if you started at the beginning of your course/textbook, without skipping (boring) parts

Comment: you know I just realized that before you posted. i was so caught up with arrays and classes that I forgot calling methods was a thing, just a brain fart on my end. thank you for all the help btw

Comment: First of all you must improve your question. Add the parameter in `getTotal(List<double> items)`. Now where in this code getTotal() is being called??

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
accumulator = items[i].getPrice();
```

or

```
accumulator = items[i].getSubTotal();
```